# Is this programmatically a bad idea?

Tags: database, asp-classic, ado

Currently I'm trying to create some coding short cuts for our website. Right now to query a database and return a record set 2 functions have to be called:

`GetDBConn` returns an open ado connection object to the connection string passed in.

`GetRS` returns a record set object based on the ado connection and sql passed in.

```
set objConn = GetDBConn(connString, commandTimeout, connTimeout, cursorType)
set objRs   = GetRS(objConn, sql)
```

I want to essentially write those two as a single function but my question really becomes this... I am pretty sure that you're supposed to close and destroy your ado connections when done with them. If I `dim` the connection inside the new function, query the database and return the record set, I can't close and destroy the connection inside the function or else the record set returned by the function becomes useless (i.e. that connection object is never explicitly closed/destroyed). Is that ok? Will it have any negative impact on the SQL/Web Servers?

Thanks

Comment: Please pay more attention to your tag choices... check the description for the `ASP` tag before the next time you use it.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: Sorry, my bad. Will do in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not closing connections will cause problems with your SQL server's resources. Depending on your hardware and how many connections are getting established, you may not notice a problem. Or it may make the server inaccessible...

Answer (score 2):

Using it for record sets is probably not a good idea (too easy to forget to close them), however opening / closing a connection shouldn't be a problem. I use the following two functions on all my legacy Classic ASP sites:

`conn.asp`:

```
<%
Dim oConn

Sub openConn()
    Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    oConn.Open sConn 'connection string here'
End Sub

Sub closeConn()
    If IsObject(oConn) Then
        On Error Resume Next
        If oConn.State = 1 Then
            oConn.Close
        End If
        Set oConn = Nothing
        Err.Clear
        On Error Goto 0
    End If
End Sub
%>
```

Then I include `conn.asp` and use `openConn()` once at the top of the page and `closeConn()` at the bottom.

The `On Error Resume Next` is usually regarded as a "bad coding" practice, however in this case I think it's appropriate otherwise you'll be getting errors on all the pages you use `closeConn()` on for those edge cases where `oConn.State` fails for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

I've always used the dbhelper.asp provided by the MS reference app [FmStocks](http://www.fmstocks.com/)
The functions always return a disconnected recordset so you never get in trouble

The functions are like this one:

```
Function RunSQLReturnRS(sqlstmt, params())
    On Error Resume next

    ' Create the ADO objects'
    Dim rs , cmd
    Set rs = server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set cmd = server.createobject("ADODB.Command")

    ' Init the ADO objects  & the stored proc parameters'
    cmd.ActiveConnection = GetConnectionString()
    cmd.CommandText = sqlstmt
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 900 ' 15 minutes

    collectParams cmd, params

    ' Execute the query for readonly'
    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rs.Open cmd, , adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
    If err.number > 0 then
        BuildErrorMessage()
        exit function
    end if

    ' Disconnect the recordset'
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing
    Set rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing

    ' Return the resultant recordset'
    Set RunSQLReturnRS = rs

End Function
```

Comment: what is this line ?   "collectParams cmd, params"

Comment: Is another function the collects the param array and put them in the command. The source code is in the download linked in the answer.